# Get Coordinates from Angle

Tags: coordinates, formula, angle

Given an angle and having drawn a line from the center of a bounding box, how can we compute the coordinates at which the line will intersect the bounding box?

Please have a look at the following diagram:
[image]

As you can see, for example, at angle 0 the line intersects point (0.5, 1)

How can we turn this problem into a computable formula that accepts an angle and returns x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve by using trigonometry and handling each 45 degree section separately:

Given:

- xmin, xmax (limits of x axis for boxed region)
- ymin, ymax (limits of y axis for boxed region)
- a (angle)
- output coordinates of x and y
- width = (xmax - xmin)
- height = (ymax - ymin):

Angle range; x; y

- (0<= a <= 45); x = xmin + (tan(a)*(width/2) + width/2; y = ymax
- (45<= a <= 90); x = xmax; y = ymin + (tan(90-a)*height/2) + height/2
- (90<= a <= 135); x = xmax;y = ymin + (tan(a-90)*height/2) + height/2
- (135<= a <= 180); x = xmin + (tan(180-a)*width/2)+width/2; y = ymin
- (180<= a <= 225); x = xmin - (tan(a-180)*width/2)+width/2; y = ymin
- (225<= a <= 270); x = xmin; y = ymin -(tan(270-a)*height/2)+height/2
- (270<= a <= 315); x = xmin; y = ymin + (tan(a-270)*height/2)+height/2
- (315<= a <= 360); x = xmin -(tan(360-a)*width/2)+width/2; y = ymax